# Query in android sql-lite to find the entries made in between two dates which are saved as year, month and day

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In a database I have saved the date in form of 3 columns: Year, Month, Day_of_Month
( I know it might not be a best way to save the date but I make certain other queries for which this format felt suitable.)

Now I wish to get all the rows where the date is in between two specified dates. I went through previous stackoverflow questions, but most of them have saved the date as a single entity.

This is how I tried:

I have a MySqLiteHelper class with all the column names declared. I also create the table there. COLUMN_DATE_YEAR, COLUMN_DATE_MONTH and COLUMN_DATE_DAY are the string storing the column names.

```
      int fyear, fmonth, fday; // I populate those initial date values
      int tyear, tmonth, tday; // I populate those target date values

      String selection = MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_YEAR + " >= '"+fyear+"' AND "+ MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_DAY + " >= '"+fday+"' AND "
              + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_MONTH + " >= '"+fmonth+"' AND " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_YEAR + " <= '"+tyear+"' AND "
              + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_DAY + " <= '"+ tday+"' AND "+ MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_MONTH + " <= '"+tmonth+"'";

      String []column = {MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MOOD_LEVEL};
      Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAMES, column, selection, null, null, null, null);
```

Now the problem with this approach is that it will give no results for the query between 25 Feb 2013 and 17 March 2013 as the date 25th > 17th, even though the month 2 < 3. This might require some kind of nested where clause. However I am unable to form a nested 'Where' using '.query' method.

Please suggest a way to query for the entries stored in between these two dates. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these three data types declared as `TEXT` or `INTEGER` in your table? And are you using `2` for February or `Feb` in your Strings?

Comment: I've stored everything as String in the database. The months are  stored as 1 to 12. In the query, the fmonth, tmonth variables also vary between 1 to 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why you shouldn't be able to run a somewhat more complex WHERE clause, as follows (for date >= 2013-02-17):

```
( YEAR > 2013 OR ( YEAR = 2013 AND ( MONTH > 2 OR ( MONTH = 2 AND DAY >= 17 ) ) ) )
```

This will work, but it's for from optimal. You'd be better off correcting your database design.

Correction: You *must* fix your database design. Either store the date as `DATE` type or as ISO string: `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Bonus: Say you have the following right now:

```
CREATE TABLE theTable( 
    ....
    THEYEAR TEXT,
    THEMONTH TEXT,
    THEDAY TEXT );
```

To convert the date to a usable format, you can simply run the following:

```
ALTER TABLE theTable
  ADD COLUMN THEDATE TEXT;

UPDATE theTable
    SET THEDATE = THEYEAR || substr( '0' || '-' || THEMONTH, -2, 2 ) || '-' || substr( '0' || THEDAY, -2, 2 );
```

Once you've done that, you can then query using the `BETWEEN` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe that the 'must' is having lot of experience behind it. So, I'll change my database design. I should have thought it thorough before I made this decision of storing yyyy, mm, dd separately. :-|

Comment: I added the "must" after I read in comments above that your yyyy/mm/dd fields are `TEXT`. Numbers, of course, ought to be `INTEGER` and having associated numbers stored as dissociated `TEXT` columns will make working with your database extremely difficult. Further, having to inspect three columns five times rather than one column once will slow down your queries and preclude you from using index searches.

Answer (score 1):

Using your current schema, try reordering your WHERE clause.  You need to compare the largest columns first, i.e. *year, month, **day***.  With your current *year, **day**, month* you cannot accurately compare dates that cross over into new months.
For example: day >= 25 and day <= 17 creates an invalid range. It doesn't account for the correct range: >25, wrap to 1, then <17...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sam. I tried using BETWEEN clause. If I use 'between' clause, then the invalid range problem should solve, right? I am not sure. However, changing the scehma seems to be a better idea for now. Though, it would be a pain.

Comment: You can use `BETWEEN` but you must compare _year, month, day_. Though "simplifying" your schema to use one column might be best in the long run.  (I prefer storing date/times as milliseconds.) You can easily create a new table with the exist data with a wise `CREATE TABLE` statement, one that simply concatenates the columns YEAR, MONTH, DAY into a new column `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: Cool. That's a good idea. Thanks for your input. I might go with it.

Comment: Sam, I actually don't think "reordering [the] WHERE clause will fix the problem -- see the answer above. That said, I added the update script to the accepted answer, which contains the concatenation as an UPDATE. A new table is not required.

Comment: I prefer using a new table.  If we're making a new column to replace three old columns, why keep the old columns around? SQLite's `ALTER TABLE` doesn't support `DROP`, so a new table makes sense to me. Simply calling `CREATE TABLE Foo AS select-stmt` will do it all in one command.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the table structure the below query will work for you, try it

```
select * from TableName WHERE (10000*ColumnYear+100*ColumnMonth+ColumnDay >= 20131009) and (10000*ColumnYear+100*ColumnMonth+ColumnDay <= 20131121);
```